# wp-login.php not working goes back to home page

Tags: login

If i enter mydomain/wp-login.php it does not open the sign in page but goes back to the home page. However, if i enter mydomain/wp-admin its working it opens the sign in page and it shows the url https://mydomain/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fmydomain%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1

I use buddyboss theme and the header in the front end "sign in" links to wp-login.php and since its going back to the homepage we cannot sign in. How to change the link to wp-admin or fix my wp-login.php

I disabled all plugins but its the same problem.

Comment: Is there any chance you are logged in but with a user that doesn't have permission to access wp-admin? (Although I don't think that's exactly the behaviour you'd see)

Comment: Yes i tried to login using a subscriber and its ok. But i have to type in the url mydomain/wp-admin for the login screen to appear. If i click the sign in link in the frontend the login screen does not appear because the sign in link is to wp-login.php. The problem is still why wp-login.php does not show the login screen.

Comment: I created a staging site and strangely the wp-login.php is working however when i push back the staging to live site including the database again in the live site its not working. what wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved: After creating a staging site the wp-login is working then I push it back to live site, at first the live site still not working but after 1 day its now working. I did not make other changes so i guess its the cache.

Comment: Glad you solved it, but you probably need to fix your cache configuration then: you shouldn't be caching wp-admin, and probably not wp-login either, for exactly this reason.